# default classpath entries for new projects

Tags: eclipse

how to make the .classpath file entries as a default set of classpath entries (i.e., as a template) for all the newly created projects. this saves our time adding the same classpath entries to the new project again.

yes copy pasting the .classpath file helps, but I wanted to make it as a default template so as to reuse for all the new projects

Thanks
Vikram

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly there are no project templates, that you can define in eclipse. The only way is to write an eclipse plugin and  create a custom Project creator.